# jquery codes dont work on my plugin wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use this to hook my scripts and styles to my plugin

```
add_action('admin_init', 'the_box_init' );

// Init plugin options to white list our options
function the_box_init(){
    register_setting( 'the_box_options', 'the_box', 'the_box_validate' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myprefix-style', plugins_url('theboxstyle.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myprefix-script', plugins_url('theboxjs.js', __FILE__) ); //this hook my custom js, preferrably which contents almost my jquery codes.

}
```

however, the jquery codes doesn't work even in this simple codes (refer below)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
alert("asdasd");
});
```

and only javascript did work..

what does suppose my implementation get wrong that jquery didnt work?

im open in any suggestions, recommendations and idea's. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your code in a closure:

```
(function($){
    alert("asdasd");
})(jQuery);
```

or:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("asdasd");
});
```

This will helps you to prevent the conflict between `Wordpress` and `jQuery`